# My cat and I fell on the stairs

Tags: cats, injury

I fell on the stairs while carrying my cat in my arms. We fell about 4 stairs as my slippers slipped. My cat's upper body was on my chest with his paws on my shoulder, and I fell with my chest up and back facing the stairs. When it ended, my cat was walking in front of me without any limping or anything.

I just want to know if he is okay, and what are the signs of injury. I didn't suspect any injury, but still, please help me to identify what to look and where to look. There are not enough vets near me who are experienced with cats.

My cat is 5 months old, 2.8 kg, and is a traditional long hair Persian male.

Comment: Unless you fell on the cat at one point, there should be no need. You must be in a worse shape, as probably he sank his nails in your skin.

Comment: @C.Koca thank you for your reply ,we are ok and i checked his movements he is running playing like normal and he was on me during the fall not the other way around and i was saved from his nails .thanks for your help